# Expectation and Variance of Infinite Sequence

Tags: probability, expected-value

We have an infinite sequence of independent variables where we take k labelled balls and put them into k labelled slots so that there is one ball per slot. We want to find the expected value and variance of Xn (the number of balls that have been placed in a slot matching their number). So, X1, X2,.... is an infinite sequence.

I am mainly struggling with how to approach the question. Why is it infinite if we only have k balls?

Should I start with indicator functions?

Comment: Kindly include your work.

Comment: You need to clarify your description.  The balls are numbered?  The slots are numbered?  You seem to be asking about one variable.  Why the sequence?

Comment: You repeat the drawing (the permutation) infinitely many times.